# How to detect which variable is 'nonetype' in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using TensorFlow to create a new model, which includes a dynamic loop. I am using tf.while_loop to implement this instance. One issue I encounter is that:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'back_prop'`

This problem appears while doing

```
gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, params)
```

Then, I try to print all the `params` and it turns out every parameter has a shape. I think if there is a `nonetype` parameter, its shape should be `None` as well? On the other hand, is there any other method that could help me detect which variable is not assigned or like `[]`?

Here is full trackback:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 125, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "main.py", line 119, in main
    train()# if FLAGS.train:
  File "main.py", line 95, in train
    model = create_model(sess, False)
  File "main.py", line 75, in create_model
    forward_only=False)
  File "/home/sniu/lab/ai_lab/DMN-tensorflow/models/DMN.py", line 248, in __init__
    gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 481, in gradients
    in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_grad.py", line 181, in _EnterGrad
    if not grad_ctxt.back_prop:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'back_prop'
```

Comment: Post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

`NoneType` just means that the value is `None`

```
>>> item = None
>>> item.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

You can see if you call `type` on `None`

```
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

`None` is kind of a special value in python.  It's a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object.  It's an instance of `NoneType`, and all `None`'s are the exact same object.

Generally, to prevent these types of errors people either test if the value is `None` first, or they wrap the expression in a `try/except` block

```
if item is not None:
    print item.back_prop
```

Or using a `try/except`

```
try:
    item.back_prop
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Be aware that the `try/except` block may suppress other `AttributeErrors` unrelated to `item` being `None`, like if `item` is some other value that *also* doesn't have a `back_prop` attribute.  You may want to treat that situation differently than if `item` is `None`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Brendan. I am using the method provided by you `type( variable)`, but since I am using TensorFlow, this method only give me ` <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable'> `. I think, there is something wrong with my program while creating the TensorFlow graph. I need to know which Tensor is not assigned.

Comment: @HanyuGuo Were you able to solve this problem? I'm facing the same issue!

Comment: @Mr.Robot It usually because you break the computation graph making some part of the graph not differentiable. I would suggest you to check the cond and body whether or not they are included in the computation graph. Hope this would help.

Comment: @HanyuGuo Thank you for the response! I was able to solve and the problem was indeed as you described. I fixed the while loop code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783#issuecomment-173403634), I resolved a similar issue with gradients that were None.

```
opt = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(1e-3)
grads, vars = zip(
    *opt.compute_gradients(loss, var_list=my_varlist))
grads = [g if g is not None else tf.zeros_like(v)
         for g, v in zip(grads, vars)]
optim = opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, vars))
```